# complex nested list to a clean matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, nested, nested-lists

I have struggled for two days longs to find a way to create a specific matrix from a nested list

First of all, I am sorry if I don't explain my issue correctly I am one week new to StackOverflow* and R (and programming...)!

I use a file that you can find there :

- original link: https://parltrack.org/dumps/ep_mep_activities.json.lz
- Uncompressed by me here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/701b7ac5250f451c6cb26d29b41bd88020200808183632/bb08429ca5102e3dc277f2f44d08f82220200808183652/666973
- first 3 lists and last one (out of 23905) past here: https://pastebin.com/Kq7mjis5

With *rjson*, I have a nested list like this :
[Nested list of MEP Votes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFmuM.png)

```
List of 23905
 $ :List of 7
  ..$ ts     : chr "2004-12-16T11:49:02"
  ..$ url    : chr "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/RegData/seance_pleniere/proces_verbal/2004/12-16/votes_nominaux/xml/P6_PV(2004)12-16(RCV)_XC.xml"
  ..$ voteid : num 7829
  ..$ title  : chr "Projet de budget gÃ©nÃ©ral 2005 modifiÃ© - bloc 3"
  ..$ votes  :List of 3
  .. ..$ +:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ total : num 45
  .. .. ..$ groups:List of 6
  .. .. .. ..$ ALDE   :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : Named num 4404
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mepid"
  .. .. .. ..$ GUE/NGL:List of 25
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : Named num 28469
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mepid"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : Named num 4298
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mepid"
```

then my goal is to have something like this :
[final matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z3e0.png)

First I would like to keep only the lists (from [[1]] to [[23905]]) containing   $vote$+$groups$Renew or $vote$-$groups$Renew or $vote$'0'$groups$Renew. The main list (the 23905) are registered votes. My work is on the Renew group so my only interest is to have a vote where the Renew groups exist to compare them with other groups.

After that my goal is to create a matrix like this all the [[x]] where we can find groups$Renewexists:
[final matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z3e0.png)

```
 V1             V2 (not mandatory)   V3[[x]]$voteid
[mepid==666] GUE/NGL     + (mepid==[666] is found in [[1]]$vote$+$groups$GUE/NGL)              
[mepid==777] Renew       - (mepid==[777] is found in [[1]]$vote$-$groups$GUE/NGL)
```

I want to create a matrix so I can process the votes of each MEP (referenced by their MEPid). Their votes are either + (for yea), - (for nay) or 0 (for abstain). Moreover, I would like to have political groups of MEP displayed in the column next to their mepid. We can find their political group thanks to the place where their votes are stored. If the mepid is shown in the list [[x]]$vote$+$groups$GUE/NGL she or he belongs to the GUE/NGL groups.

What I want to do might look like this

```
# Clean the nested list
Keep Vote[[x]] if Vote[[x]] list contain ,
$vote$+$groups$Renew, 
or $vote$-$groups$Renew,
or $vote$'0'$groups$Renew

# Create the matrix (or a data.frame if it is easier)
VoteMatrix <- as.matrix(
V1 = all "mepid" found in the nested list
V2 = groups (name of the list where we can find the mepid) (not mandatory)
V3 to Vy = If.else(mepid is in [[x]]$vote$+ then “+”,
mepid is in [[x]]$vote$- then “-“, "0")
)
```

Thank you in advance,

*Nevertheless, I am reading this website actively since I started R!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your question into a more readable format. As it stands, it is difficult to asses your desired output.

Comment: @mhh I updated the format of my question I hope it is clear now. Tell me if it is not. Thank you very much for your warm and quick welcoming!

Comment: @IRTFM I uploaded the JSON file on WeTransfer and the first three lists on pastebin.com I hope it answers your transparency wish.

Comment: It does. Unfortunately it's not obvious to me that this is a list structure that immediately can be dropped into a data.frame. You apparently understand the data somewhat better and have something in mind about how it could be cast into a rectangular format, but I certainly do not see which leaves and by which rules that can be accomplished.since the length of the data structure is only 3, there is not a good correspondence to your request for "from [[1]] to [[23905]]", and the lengths of the three top sublists are only 7, 9 and 9 respectively.

Comment: @IRTFM. Thank you for your answer! Maybe there is a function that can extract the data to make it rectangular? I tried to create some "function" in an edit of my post. I am looking at purrrr right now but sadly my lack of knowledge about R makes this research very difficult. If I understand the JSON well enough, When I talk about [[1]] to [[23905]] I am not listing the sublists but only the first list in the JSON file, those contain the sublist you mentioned.

Comment: I think I can demonstrate how to select the sublists that contain "Renew" values, although I still don't know what a value of "Renew" might mean in the real world. In the meantime it appears you do not yet understand that `+`. `-`. and `0` cannot be names that follow a `$` operator. They must be quoted. Furthermore the sublist names are "votes", not "vote". I'm assuming you do not want all that extra verbiage in the matrix such as "is found in [[1]]" ..... or do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that the `'votes'` sublist is composed of three items a list of member numbers stored within what I think are party designators. Here's how you might "straighten" the positive voter 'memids' by party:

```
str( unlist(  sapply(names(jlis[[1]]$votes$'+'$groups), function(x) unlist(jlis[[1]]$votes$'+'$groups[[x]]) ) ) )
 Named num [1:104] 28268 4514 28841 28314 28241 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:104] "ALDE.mepid" "ALDE.mepid" "ALDE.mepid" "ALDE.mepid" ...
```

You get a named numeric vector with 108 entries. Perhaps this will demonstrate what sort of terminology to use in better describing your desired result. (Just giving a partial schema for the desired result leaves way too much ambiguity to support a fully formed request.)

I do NOT see the number 23905 anywhere in what I downloaded from your link. We are clearly looking at different data. I see this for the timestamp: `chr "2004-12-01T15:20:31"`. I'm not going to cut you any slack for not knowing R, since the task needs to be fully explained in a natural language. I will cut you slack regarding grammar if English is not your native tongue, but you definitely need to make a better effort at explication. This is what I see for the names with the `votes$'+'$groups` sublists of the first three items, but since RENEW is not in any of them there's not a lot that could be demonstrated about picking items:

```
> names( jlis[[1]]$votes$'+'$groups)
[1] "ALDE"    "GUE/NGL" "IND/DEM" "NI"      "PPE-DE"  "PSE"     "UEN"    
> names( jlis[[2]]$votes$'+'$groups)
[1] "GUE/NGL" "IND/DEM" "NI"      "PPE-DE" 
> names( jlis[[3]]$votes$'+'$groups)
[1] "ALDE"      "GUE/NGL"   "IND/DEM"   "NI"        "PPE-DE"    "PSE"       "UEN"       "Verts/ALE"
```

Furthermore, when I looked at all of the possible votes values using this method (for all three of the items you made available) I still see no `RENEW` names.

```
sapply( jlis[[1]]$votes[c("+","-","0")], function(x) names(x$groups) )
```

After second edit: Here's the next step of isolating those votes that contain a "Renew` value. I'm assuming that its possible to have a "Renew" value in only one of the three possible 'votes' values (+,-.0). If not (and there are always "Renew" values in each of them when there is one in any of them) then you might be able to simplify the logic. We make three logical vectors:

```
 sapply( seq_along(MEPVotes)  , function(i){ 'Renew' %in% names( MEPVotes[[i]]$votes[['0']][['groups']]) } )
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 sapply( seq_along(MEPVotes)  , function(i){ 'Renew' %in% names( MEPVotes[[i]]$votes[['+']][['groups']]) } )
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 sapply( seq_along(MEPVotes)  , function(i){ 'Renew' %in% names( MEPVotes[[i]]$votes[['-']][['groups']]) } )
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

And then wrap them in a `matrix` call with 3 columns and take the maximum of each row (the maximum of c(TRUE,FALSE) is 1 and then convert back to logical.

```
selection_vec = as.logical( apply( matrix( c( 
   sapply( seq_along(MEPVotes)  , function(i){ 'Renew' %in% names( MEPVotes[[i]]$votes[['0']][['groups']]) } ),
   sapply( seq_along(MEPVotes)  , function(i){ 'Renew' %in% names( MEPVotes[[i]]$votes[['+']][['groups']]) } ),
   sapply( seq_along(MEPVotes)  , function(i){ 'Renew' %in% names( MEPVotes[[i]]$votes[['-']][['groups']]) } ) ),
                                             ncol=3 ), 1,max))

> selection_vec
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and your commitment to my issue. I am sorry about my English grammar. As I try to improve it every day (I am not a native speaker), feel free to tell me when it is atrocious! Concerning the 23905 numbers of list. As you can see in my edited question, I got it thanks to rjson package and the file shared on wetransfer.W hen I do sapply(MEPVote[[23905]]$votes[c("+","-","0")], function(x) names(x$groups) ) I find "Renew" in the three groups.

Comment: Then you have your answer? Or are perhaps getting closer? Do note that your code only looks at the last one out of the 23905 possible items in that MEPVote data object. I do see that the fourth item in you amended data example does have "Renew" name in each of the votes categories. I'm quite sure we could construct a search function to identify those nodes that have "Renew" values. It might help in understanding this if you could say what these 'groups' names mean in the "real world". I'm guessing they are political parties? And I'm guessing that +,- and 0 are 'yea', 'nay' and 'abstain' votes?

Comment: We are getting closer I think, thank you for your patience! I updated my question with the "real world" words. I hope it will help you to understand my issue as I completely do not know how to solve and I am sadly still stuck! R is not as easy as it seems haha!

Comment: I've offered a solution to the selection portion of your multipart question. You should mark this question as answered. I suggest you now work on one of the qualifying MEPVotes sublists at a time and then make a function that can be applied one sublist at a time to the qualifying items in that large JSON derived list that you have. For your currently offered data that would be the value of `dput(MEPVotes[[4]]` . Make a matrix that has the desired structure. If you cannot do that yourself, then post another question with that as a starting point, since SO does not like multipart questions.